# Asymptote returns errors with labels

Tags: labels, asymptote, ghostscript

When trying to run a simple Asymptote example I get errors with creating labels.  My Ghostscript version is 10.02, Asmptote v2.86 in Windows 10.

For example, running

```
import three;
currentprojection=perspective(0,0,1,up=Y);
label(scale(4)*"$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\alpha x^2}\,dx=
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}$",O,blue,Embedded);
```

returns *reading array of length 0 with out-of-bounds index 0*

I know this was an issue with old versions of Ghostscript, but this one is up to date, so I'm not sure how to resolve

Comment: Just to confirm that there is nothing wrong with the code itself: it runs fine for me (and displays in the PS viewer as well as converted to pdf with `asy -f pdf`) under Ubuntu with Asymptote 2.78 and Ghostscript 9.55.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was the break in lines 3-4.  If I re-type it without carriage returns it runs fine.